# Binding to network interface/IP address on client machine

Tags: syslog-ng

I i'm trying to figure out how to force syslog-ng on clients to bind to a specified IP address. I have multiple interfaces, and need syslog-ng to send the logs through a specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ip()` option of network sources, or `interface()`.

For example:

```
source { network(interface("wlp3s0")); };
source { network(ip("192.168.1.1")); };
```